# Transferring binary file over through RS232 using C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am looking to transfer a binary file via RS232. I need to do this to 5000 different devices (no joke). I could do them one-by-one through a terminal program but that will take a lot of time.

So, I am writing a C# program that will be able to automate the process. I am looking at using XMODEM protocol and command line parameters to start the process. I have been looking for this for a few hours now and far my results have turned up little. I tried using uCON but that takes some sort of scripting language.

I was wondering if anyone in the community here might know of a solution to transfer a file over RS232 and program it in C#. Whether it is from a protocol (XMODEM) or a program that accepts command line or some other custom solution, doesn't really matter to me.

Comment: Ok, so after more digging, I came across this: https://www.ghielectronics.com/community/codeshare/entry/825   which is nice but I am having a bit of a difficult time sending stuff to the port. But it is a start at least. I would place this as the answer if I had it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I was able to confirm that the code found on the website(  [ghielectronics.com/community/codeshare/entry/825](http://ghielectronics.com/community/codeshare/entry/825)) was able to work. The issue was was that I did not know how long it would take the computer to transfer the file. I thought that it would be quick. However, after further testing, it actually takes about 30 sec to 1 min depending on the file size.

This C# code snippet allows anyone to transfer a binary file over the Serial Port using the XMODEM protocol. This is done in code and a terminal is not needed which fits the requirements that I needed for the project.

Comment: Can anyone comment on why the -1? How could I fix my post to ensure that my answer is a good question